# Call Textview in Thread on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, textview

This is my code.when I click on button ,it call **yourcountry()** function then **yourcountry()** in a thread call **location()**. I get data from **http://192.168.4.1/led/0**  with WIFI connection. while-loop runs about 25 times and then it appears  **Unfortunately app has stopped** .I think the problem is in :

```
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { 
               country.setText(show);
            }
        });
```

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public   Button button;
    public   TextView country;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.button);
        country=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                yourcountry();
            }
        });
    } // end of oncreate



    public void yourcountry() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                location();
            }
        }).start();
    }



    private void location() {
        //   while (true) {

        while (true){
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.4.1/led/0");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String data = "", line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    data += line+"\n" ;
                }
                show = data;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() { 
                       country.setText(show);
                    }
                });

                sleep(50);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) 
            {
                Log.e("error", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }//end of while

    } //end location


}//end of class
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: Try checking the log for the root of the problem

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski can you tell me clearly? in that link i was confused

Answer (score 0):

Calling a runnable from a new thread doesn't put it in the main thread.

I think you would have better luck wrapping your functions in an AsyncTask.  You can do all of your UI work in the

```
onPostExecute()
```

Otherwise, you need to wrap your runnable in a handler to ensure you're running it on the UI thread.

Edit::

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public  TextView country;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        country=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.country) ;
      new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }//on creaate

    static boolean shouldRun = true;
    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
         boolean firstRun = true;


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (!firstRun) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            } else {
                firstRun = false;
            }
            String data = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.4.1/led/0");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.connect();
                inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                data = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    data += line + "\n";
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                data = null;
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
            super.onPostExecute(data);
            if (data != null) {
                country.setText(data);
            }
            if (shouldRun) {
                new MyAsyncTask().execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call:

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

And Permission:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
> ```

Edit::

While(true) isn't good practice, since you have no breaks set. This will run forever (which you don't want).

You can spin off another async task when the first one finishes under some condition.

Comment: can you describe your idea with example?

Comment: what is the result in onPoseExecute ?

Comment: what should i write instead of result? result do not work.  Error:(607, 33) error: cannot find symbol variable result

Comment: So sorry. I took this from a snippet I wrote earlier today. Put "data" in where "result" is. I'll edit my post

Comment: Note:one thing, if I return data ,while-loob runs one time.it is while loop, its condition is true ,it is forever.

Comment: Are you hitting an exception? If it gets caught the app won't break.

Comment: calculateSignalLevel rssi:-67,numLevels:5,signalLevel:3  ////it shows it in android device monitor

Comment: I'm not sure what you've written at this point, but I have edited my post with a more in depth example. I wrote it on my phone, so I'm hoping there aren't any typos.

Comment: dear i saw you change your code ,and i understand ....can u see this  code.can it help us?

Comment: Your last comment didn't contain any relevant information. I do not see any other changes to your original post or otherwise.

Comment: I see them now.

Comment: i want my loop works for ever it get data from wifi modem.

Comment: i see it now please let me try it.

Comment: dear ,i use your code but i need test my device for 12hours,i invite new device ,thanks for your help... i use your code and i hope it work ,tell you all things in 12 hours later.

Comment: Just be sure to come back and accept my answer when it works =)

Comment: :(  it failed in 3 minites.

Comment: dear my device help people it save people life ,i am glad to invite it.but i need it work without error .

Comment: how can i send you my project?

Comment: I'm going to test it myself.  I just pulled out my laptop.  You can send it in dropbox or google drive if you like

Comment: I send you here tomorrow. i am tired now...I didn't sleep a wink last night  .thanks for your help i send you .

Comment: No problem. I am currently testing and I've been running for 5+ minutes so far with no problem.

I am updating my post with the code I am running.

Comment: yesterday you was  83 but now 133 reputation. :))))) i have helped you..

Comment: I'm glad I could help. That took a good while to get done lol

Comment: Sure.  What's your email?  I'll send you mine there.  Thanks,

Comment: i accept all your answer and question in stackoverflaw .you were 83 now 213  :))))))))))))) when you have a friend you can advance. i have been here for about 3 or 4  years but i have earned 19 reputation.you in one day have earnrd 130 .dont forget me.

Comment: Dear,
your MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity, if we extend MainActivity  with Fragment  , it dosent work.how can we solve this issue?